# Streaming RTMP mixing more sounds

Tags: windows, audio, audio-streaming, rtmp, mixing

I'm trying to find some software for Windows for mixing sound card output and microphone output and then sending it to the RTMP server. Is there a way to mix the two sound streams not in audio hardware card, but using some software?
Thanks for attempting to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

You may try vMix http://www.vmix.com.au/. Although is it primarily for Video Mixing, but does Audio Mixing too.

Answer (score 0):

I just got Wirecast.  Pretty new to it. I think the pro level would do it.

I am also going to try out XSplit Broadcaster and XSplit Gamecaster.  Maybe their free versions would work.

Also, always look into Barix. That's amazing.  It's a box you get that can do wonders... instreamer and exstreamer... believe they call those 2. They're a few hundred each though.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.